# My For Loop isn't deleting all the rows I want (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

I'm trying to get my For loop to delete all the 0s in a column from my sheet but it seems to be leaving about 9 rows out that have a 0. The 0s are in a column from a previous procedure that uses the InStr function and the 9 0s are due to the function not being able to find the substring. Not sure if this where the issues lies. There's about 50,000 rows in my sheet.

```
Sub removeZeros()

Dim rng As Range, i As Long
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range(Range("G2"), Range("G2").End(xlDown))

For i = rng.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
    If rng.Cells(i, 3).Value = 0 Then rng.Cells(i).EntireRow.Delete
Next i

End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You are aware that you check with `rng.Cells(i, 3).Value = 0`the value in column I? And you also aware that in case the cell contains a string the comparision  `rng.Cells(i, 3).Value = 0` will be `true`?

Comment: I'm not experienced in VBA, but I can remember that an empty column could have make such a problem too - I'm not sure, if that's the case here - could it be that these 9 0s are right after each other?

Comment: @Storax isn't that like this, `rng.Cells(rows , cols)`, if then it's actually correct

Comment: Yes, in case the cell is empty the comparision `rng.Cells(i, 3).Value = 0` will also be true. If you want to check the value in column **I** then you have to debug and check for `rng.Cells(i, 3).Value = 0` to be true. You could add a `Debug.Assert rng.Cells(i, 3).Value <> 0`before `If rng.Cells(i, 3).Value = 0 Then rng.Cells(i).EntireRow.Delete` then the code will stop whenever `rng.Cells(i, 3).Value = 0` is true.

Comment: `Set rng = Range("G2:G" & cells(rows.count,"G").end(xlup).row)`

Comment: @Davesexcel I'm still getting 0s that being left out, there's 10 now

Comment: If you know the cells whre the check fails then write code which does the check on these specific cells or even on only one of the cells and try to find out why it fails. Without knowing what is in the cell it is difficult to tell.

Comment: What happens if you run the code twice? Does it still ignore the 10 zeroes, or does it delete them on the second pass?

Comment: @CLR It still ignores the 10 0s

Comment: That would suggest that the cells don't *really* contain zeros, just a value that when the current formatting is applied *looks* like a zero. Either that, or something is preventing the deletion of a row, such as merged cells, protected ranges etc. - though these would normally throw an error unless you've disabled errors.

Answer (score 0):

As you know which cells fail the comparision `rng.Cells(i, 3).Value = 0`  you could use the following code to get closer to the issue

```
Sub CheckCell()

    Dim i As Long
    
    Dim v As Variant
    Dim rg As Range
    
    i = 10
    Set rg = Range("I" & i)
    v = rg.Value
    Debug.Print v, TypeName(v), rg.Value = 0
    
End Sub
```

Just replace `i = 10`  with the row where the check fails. Of course, you could also [debug](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/excel_macros/excel_macros_debugging_code.htm) but that seems to be out of your knowledge right now. Or you try [assertions](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-assert/) to get closer to the root cause

Comment: Do I run this sub after I've done my sub or before? Also, I'm checking the 0s in the J column, is that an issue?

Comment: That does not matter you just have to adjust the line `i= 10 ` with the correct number. If line 10 should be deleted then leave the 10. If line 234 should be deleted then cahnge it to 234. This code will not modify any data and it will not fix the problem. It should get you closer to the cause of the problem.

Comment: They've all come back as,   0        Double        True

Also, all the ones left have been given a 0 by the InStr function, from the previous sub, as the substring wasn't found

Comment: Hmm, bad news for this test. Then I am out of hints without seeing any data and more information on hwo they were created.

Comment: Is there anyway I could send you the file and my subs?

Comment: I am afraid not

Comment: Okay, no worries. Thanks for all help though! :)

Comment: I think you have to learn how to debug and then set a breakpoint for the lines which are affected and then step through the code

Comment: Sorry if this is asking too much but do you have some code to do that? I've just started to code VBA

Comment: This is something you have to to. Please have a look at the links I provided in my answer

Comment: Okay, thanks again!